# MPSC Queue: Race Condition

Tags: multithreading, c++17, race-condition, producer-consumer, task-queue

I am trying to implement a lock-free Multi Producer Single Consumer Queue based on [this one written in C](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/intrusive-mpsc-node-based-queue) by Dmitry Vyukov.

The single test that I've written so far almost works. But the consumer usually misses exactly one item, either the first or the second. Occasionally, the consumer will miss about half of the inputs.

As it is now, it's not lock free. It locks every time it uses the `new` operator, but I hope to get it working and write some more exhaustive tests before messing around with allocators.

```
// src/MpscQueue.hpp

#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <optional>

/**
 * Adapted from http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/intrusive-mpsc-node-based-queue
 * @tparam T
 */
template< typename T >
class MpscQueue {
public:
    MpscQueue() {
        stub.next.store( nullptr );
        head.store( &stub );
        tail = &stub;
    }

    void push( const T& t ) {
        emplace( t );
    }

    void push( T&& t ) {
        emplace( std::move( t ));
    }

    template< typename ... Args >
    void emplace( Args...args ) {
        auto node = new Node{ std::make_unique<T>( std::forward<Args>( args )... ), nullptr };
        push( node );
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the queue and returns a unique pointer to it.
     *
     * If the queue is empty returns a unique pointer set to nullptr
     *
     * @return A unique ptr to the popped item
     */
    std::unique_ptr<T> pop() {
        Node* tailCopy = tail;
        Node* next     = tailCopy->next.load();
        auto finalize = [ & ]() {
            tail = next;
            std::unique_ptr<Node> p( tailCopy ); // free the node memory after we return
            return std::move( tail->value );
        };

        if ( tailCopy == &stub ) {
            if ( next == nullptr ) return nullptr;
            tail     = next;
            tailCopy = next;
            next     = next->next;
        }

        if ( next ) return std::move( finalize());

        if ( tail != head.load()) return nullptr;

        push( &stub );
        next = tailCopy->next;

        return next ? std::move( finalize()) : nullptr;
    }

private:
    struct Node {
        std::unique_ptr<T> value;
        std::atomic<Node*> next;
    };

    void push( Node* node ) {
        Node* prev = head.exchange( node );
        prev->next = node;
    }

    Node               stub;
    std::atomic<Node*> head;
    Node* tail;
};

// test/main.cpp

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "OCUnusedMacroInspection"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test_module
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

// test/utils.hpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template< class T >
void removeFromBothIfIdentical( std::vector<T>& a, std::vector<T>& b ) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    while ( i < a.size() && j < b.size()) {
        if ( a[ i ] == b[ j ] ) {
            a.erase( a.begin() + i );
            b.erase( b.begin() + j );
        }
        else if ( a[ i ] < b[ j ] ) ++i;
        else if ( a[ i ] > b[ j ] ) ++j;
    }
}

namespace std {
    template< typename T >
    std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& ostream, const std::vector<T>& container ) {
        if ( container.empty())
            return ostream << "[]";
        ostream << "[";
        std::string_view separator;
        for ( const auto& item: container ) {
            ostream << item << separator;
            separator = ", ";
        }
        return ostream << "]";
    }
}

template< class T >
std::vector<T> extractDuplicates( std::vector<T>& container ) {
    auto           iter = std::unique( container.begin(), container.end());
    std::vector<T> duplicates;
    std::move( iter, container.end(), back_inserter( duplicates ));
    return duplicates;
}

#define CHECK_EMPTY( container, message ) \
BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE( (container).empty(), (message) << ": " << (container) )

// test/MpscQueue.cpp
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "cert-err58-cpp"

#include <thread>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "../src/MpscQueue.hpp"
#include "utils.hpp"

using std::thread;
using std::vector;
using std::back_inserter;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( MpscQueueTestSuite )

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( two_producers ) {
        constexpr int  until = 1000;
        MpscQueue<int> queue;

        thread producerEven( [ & ]() {
            for ( int i = 0; i < until; i += 2 )
                queue.push( i );
        } );

        thread producerOdd( [ & ]() {
            for ( int i = 1; i < until; i += 2 )
                queue.push( i );
        } );

        vector<int> actual;

        thread consumer( [ & ]() {
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( 2ms );
            while ( auto n = queue.pop())
                actual.push_back( *n );
        } );

        producerEven.join();
        producerOdd.join();
        consumer.join();

        vector<int> expected( until );
        std::iota( expected.begin(), expected.end(), 0 );

        std::sort( actual.begin(), actual.end());

        vector<int> duplicates = extractDuplicates( actual );
        removeFromBothIfIdentical( expected, actual );

        CHECK_EMPTY( duplicates, "Duplicate items" );
        CHECK_EMPTY( expected, "Missing items" );
        CHECK_EMPTY( actual, "Extra items" );
    }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: Which processor architecture are you running the tests on?

Comment: @SegFault, i64. Specifically Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Comment: Did the test pass on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

My multi-producer, single consumer example below is written in Ada. I offer this as a source of virtual "pseudo-code" for your consideration. The example comes in three files.

The example implements a simple data logger with multiple producers, a shared buffer, and a single consumer that logs strings produced by the producers.

The first file is the package specification for the shared buffer. Ada package specifications define the API for entities defined in the package. In this case the entities are a protected buffer and a procedure to stop the logger.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Asynchronous Data Logger
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package Async_Logger is
   type Queue_Index is mod 256;
   type Queue_T is array (Queue_Index) of Unbounded_String;

   protected Buffer is
      entry Put (Log_Entry : in String);
      entry Get (Stamped_Entry : out Unbounded_String);
   private
      Queue   : Queue_T;
      P_Index : Queue_Index := 0;
      G_Index : Queue_Index := 0;
      Count   : Natural     := 0;
   end Buffer;

   procedure Stop_Logging;

end Async_Logger;
```

The entries in the protected Buffer allow tasks (i.e. threads) to write to the buffer and to read from the buffer. The entries automatically perform all necessary lock control of the buffer.

The implementation of the buffer code and the Stop_Logging procedure are implemented in the package body. The consumer that does the logging is also implemented in the task body, making the consumer invisible to the producing threads.

```
with Ada.Calendar;            use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting; use Ada.Calendar.Formatting;
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Async_Logger is

   ------------
   -- Buffer --
   ------------

   protected body Buffer is

      ---------
      -- Put --
      ---------

      entry Put (Log_Entry : in String) when Count < Queue_Index'Modulus is
         T_Stamp : Time             := Clock;
         Value   : Unbounded_String :=
           To_Unbounded_String
             (Image (Date => T_Stamp, Include_Time_Fraction => True) & " : " &
              Log_Entry);
      begin
         Queue (P_Index) := Value;
         P_Index         := P_Index + 1;
         Count           := Count + 1;
      end Put;

      ---------
      -- Get --
      ---------

      entry Get (Stamped_Entry : out Unbounded_String) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Stamped_Entry := Queue (G_Index);
         G_Index       := G_Index + 1;
         Count         := Count - 1;
      end Get;

   end Buffer;

   task Logger is
      entry Stop;
   end Logger;

   task body Logger is
      Phrase : Unbounded_String;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Get (Phrase);
               Put_Line (To_String (Phrase));
            or
               delay 0.01;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;

   end Logger;

   procedure Stop_Logging is
   begin
      Logger.Stop;
   end Stop_Logging;

end Async_Logger;
```

The Put entry has a guard condition allowing the entry to execute only when the buffer is not full. The Get entry has a guard condition allowing the entry to execute only when the buffer is empty.

The task named Logger is the consumer task. It runs until its Stop entry is called.

The Stop_Logging procedure calls the Logger's Stop entry.

The third file is a "main" procedure used to test the Async_Logger package. This file creates two producers, P1 and P2. Those producers each write 10 messages to the Buffer and then quit.

```
with Async_Logger; use Async_Logger;

procedure Async_Test is
   task P1;
   task P2;

   task body P1 is
   begin
      for I in 1..10 loop
         Buffer.Put(I'Image);
         delay 0.01;
      end loop;
   end P1;

   task body P2 is
      Num : Float := 0.0;
   begin
      for I in 1..10 loop
         Buffer.Put(Num'Image);
         Num := Num + 1.0;
         delay 0.01;
      end loop;
   end P2;

begin
   delay 0.2;
   Stop_Logging;
end Async_Test;
```

The Async_Test procedure simply waits for 0.2 seconds then calls Stop_Logging.

The output of a run of this program is:

```
2019-02-11 18:35:01.83 :  1
2019-02-11 18:35:01.83 :  0.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.85 :  1.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.85 :  2
2019-02-11 18:35:01.87 :  3
2019-02-11 18:35:01.87 :  2.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.88 :  3.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.88 :  4
2019-02-11 18:35:01.90 :  5
2019-02-11 18:35:01.90 :  4.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.92 :  6
2019-02-11 18:35:01.92 :  5.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.93 :  6.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.93 :  7
2019-02-11 18:35:01.95 :  7.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.95 :  8
2019-02-11 18:35:01.96 :  8.00000E+00
2019-02-11 18:35:01.96 :  9
2019-02-11 18:35:01.98 :  10
2019-02-11 18:35:01.98 :  9.00000E+00
```

Comment: I've never worked with ada before, I don't quite understand the details of how it's synchronizing everything. Is Queue a thread safe structure? Is it blocking?
Also, my goal with this is to never block except possibly when it's getting memory to create a new node.

Comment: Ada protected types and protected objects are thread safe. Each entry automatically handles locking and unlocking. The guard conditions on each entry also cause calling tasks to suspend until the guard condition evaluates to True. Blocking is needed in multi-producer single consumer patterns because each producer must write to the shared buffer only when no other producer is writing to the shared buffer, and the consumer cannot read from the shared buffer while producers are writing to the buffer. Such behaviors create race conditions and corrupted buffer states.

Comment: The code within a protected entry can be compared to a critical section in C or C++. All those actions must be executed in a way that prevents race conditions. In my example above the Buffer contains a queue as well as P_Index, C_Index and Count. These are all state variables that must be consistent with every operation on the buffer. If two producers modify the same queue element the result is data corruption or loss. Similarly, two producers attempting to update P_Index and Count at the same time will yield unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

Your push function is missing the line:

```
node->next = nullptr;
```

at the top.

See my implementation plus a lot of analysis in the comments,
here: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/threading/MpscQueue.h

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thank you! I recently moved threading related utilities to another git submodule; I fixed the link now in the post.